# How to search between the 2nd and 3rd delimiters

Tags: text-processing, file-search

So, I have a data file and I would like a match to occur only if a match is found between the 2nd and third Vertical Bars (|)

So given this data sample, I if I search for 'wilson' I want the 2nd line to return, but not the 3rd and 5th lines which also contain the term 'wilson'.

The data sample:

```
| 2015-08-21 - 10:15 | jones | view | Main.Home |  | 172.29.192.106 |
| 2015-08-21 - 10:31 | wilson | view | Main.Home |  | 172.19.6.107 |
| 2015-08-21 - 11:40 | smith | resetpasswd | wilson |  Mozilla | 172.19.15.105 |
| 2015-08-21 - 11:41 | james | view | Main.ChangePassword |  | 172.19.15.102 |
| 2015-08-21 - 11:41 | james | changepasswd | wilson |  | 172.19.15.102 |
| 2015-08-21 - 11:41 | james | view | Main.Home |  | 172.19.15.102 |
| 2015-08-22 - 08:31 | doe | view | Main.Info |  | 172.19.6.103 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your sample input:

```
$ cat /tmp/data
| 2015-08-21 - 10:15 | jones | view | Main.Home |  | 172.29.192.106 |
| 2015-08-21 - 10:31 | wilson | view | Main.Home |  | 172.19.6.107 |
| 2015-08-21 - 11:40 | smith | resetpasswd | wilson |  Mozilla | 172.19.15.105 |
| 2015-08-21 - 11:41 | james | view | Main.ChangePassword |  | 172.19.15.102 |
| 2015-08-21 - 11:41 | james | changepasswd | wilson |  | 172.19.15.102 |
| 2015-08-21 - 11:41 | james | view | Main.Home |  | 172.19.15.102 |
| 2015-08-22 - 08:31 | doe | view | Main.Info |  | 172.19.6.103 |
```

You can use awk:

```
$ awk '-F|' 'BEGIN { OFS = "|" }{ if ($3 ~ "wilson") { print }  }' /tmp/data
| 2015-08-21 - 10:31 | wilson | view | Main.Home |  | 172.19.6.107 |
```

Instead of `$3 ~ "wilson"` you could also use `$3 == " wilson "` assuming that there will always be spaces surrounding the field.

To answer your follow-up question, you could wrap it in a Bash script:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#/bin/bash
names="$(cat patlist.txt)"

for name in ${names}; do
    awk -F'|' '$3 == " '"${name}"' "' /tmp/data
done

$ cat patlist.txt
wilson
jones

$ bash foo.sh
| 2015-08-21 - 10:31 | wilson | view | Main.Home |  | 172.19.6.107 |
| 2015-08-21 - 10:15 | jones | view | Main.Home |  | 172.29.192.106 |
```

Comment: +1 a bit more terse `awk -F'|' '$3 == " wilson "' FILE`

Comment: This works well, however, if  I wanted to replace "wilson" with a list of user names say in patlist.txt, how I could I use awk this way?

Comment: @OffTheGold Replace each wilson with a different (individual) name or all of them with the same?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to tie the regex to some other field, e.g. `:[0-9][0-9] | wilson`, though this risks false positives. More complicated would be instead to use `awk` and split the data into columns, then apply the regex in `awk` against only the second column.